# Angular directive with function parameter in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to add an Angular function parameter to a directive written in TypeScript but I must not have the syntax right.  Here is an example of my directive:

```
export class NewUserDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public restrict: string = "E";
    public replace: boolean = true;
    public templateUrl: string = '/views/_dialogs/newUserDialog.html';
    public controller = Directives.NewUserController;
    public controllerAs: string = 'Ctrl';
    public bindToController: boolean = true;
    public scope: any = {
        showDialog: '=',
        saveInProgress: '=',
        onSuccessCallback: '&',
        onClosingCallback: '&'
    };
}
```

and here is a snippet of my controller:

```
export class NewUserController {
    static $inject = ["$scope", "$q", "UserServices"];

    public showDialog: boolean;
    public saveInProgress: boolean;
    public onSuccessCallback: () => void;
    public onClosingCallback: () => void;

....

    public save(): void {

        //Flag as saving
        this.saveInProgress = true;

        //Save the plan
        this.UserServices.createUser(this.newUser).then(x => {

            //When finished, hide the modal
            this.showDialog = false;

            //Let parent know new user is created
            this.onSuccessCallback();
        });
    }

}
```

Everything is working except for the function parameter in the parent controller.  I've tried a few different syntaxes in the directive implementation like this:

```
    <new-user-directive on-success-callback="loadData()" ...
```

and this:

```
    <new-user-directive on-success-callback="loadData" ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using controllerAs for the outer controller that has the `loadData` method on it? If so, then you would need to create your directive like this (assuming you named our outer controller 'Ctrl'). Notice the `Ctrl.` in front of `loadData()`

```
<new-user-directive on-success-callback="Ctrl.loadData()" ...
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, my answer is talking about the controller on the outside of the directive, which we don't know the name of. I said "assuming you named the outer controller 'Ctrl'".

Comment: Parent controller is named "c" and a total oversight on my part.  Thanks for pointing it out and it is a quick fix.  Directive syntax was working correctly.

<div ng-controller="UsersController as c">

Answer (score 1):

You have controllerAs = '**Ctrl**' so on-success-callback="**Ctrl**.loadData()"

Answer (score 0):

The methods are passed through the $scope and not on the controller.
You should create a constructor:

```
constructor(private $scope, ....){
}
```

And call the method from the $scope like so:

```
this.$scope.onSuccessCallback();
```

Comment: The directive definition object set `bindToController: true`, so the methods *would* be attached to the controller.

Comment: You are correct. I missed that one. As stated here: [exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html) you do need to use the controller name in the html like you said. upvoting your answer